# Android RecyclerView.Adapter notifyItem drives me crazy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I searched for hours but still have no explanation (even not in official docu) what is the right way to use a RecyclerView.Adapters' notify-methods. Already read a lot of similar question on SO, but no could solve my simple problem. I try to put down a short, simplified example.

```
class MyAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterClass.MyViewHolderClass> {
...
List myItemList = new ArrayList<MyItemType>();
...
}

RecyclerView  myRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecView);
myRecView.setAdapter(new MyAdapterClass(...)));
```

Even when inserting the first item, the view is not refreshed.

```
myAdapter.myItemList.add(newItem);
myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myAdapter.myItemList.size() - 1);
```

If I then tightly touch (try to scroll) the 1-item-listview, the item appears. So it seams to be a refreshing issue. But why? I have an emtpy list, then I insert one item, then I notify the adapter about the insertion. Whats wrong with my expectation?

By the way, even if I additionally call:

```
myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(myAdapter.myItemList.size() - 1);
```

it gets not automatically refreshed.

EDIT: And of course, I dont want to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` :-) only insert, update, remove on an existing list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code inside your adapter class :

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myItemList.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you define in adpter getItemCount() in list size. then used blow code for notify adapter.

```
            myadapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, userDataArrayList.size());
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But this almost would be the same like notifyDataSetChanged? I really only want to tell the listview that one item was changed, and not want to update all of them.